# Generating an outgoing call in asterisk

Tags: database, asterisk, voip

I am using asterisk 11.9.0 and i want to generate an outgoing call.I found that for outgoing i have to make a .call file and place it in a var/spool/asterisk/outgoing.I am following the link below

**http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/call-file.html#call-file-parameter**

my code is same as given in the above link,the above example uses only single fixed number to call.

My problem is that
 **i have to generate an outgoing to a number fetched from database(outgoing to new number everytime),so how to write the code of .call file for multiple numbers outgoing and how to pass these numbers fetched from database to .call file from my extensions.conf**
Is there any way to do that.
I am new to asterisk.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vicidial.org software to do that things.

Note, it is very bad idea do outboudn dialler-like app in asterisk without understanding asterisk logic and very-hi skills in programming/database.

For more info you also can use this page

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Comment: thanks @arheops for replying,i have downloaded and installed astguiclient following the steps in BASE_INSTALL.txt but when im am entering `http://localhost/vicidial/admin.php` given in step 3 of documentation my browser is giving 404 error

Comment: can i make an  outgoing to a number fetched from database by writing my own dialplan?if yes can you provide me some links related to that

Comment: If you can't install vici, that also mean you can't DEVELOP something like that. Sure there are ALOT of way deal with database. REALTIME,func_odbc,external apps/fastagi etc

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier using WombatDialer as it has a plain API where you can tell it what you want it to do and it will take care of the rest. We have a plain set up for outbound and it took maybe a couple of days from zero to what we have now. ViciDial would have been overkill.

On why rolling your own is not a great idea, the Wombat manual is quite clear: http://manuals.loway.ch/WD_UserManual-chunked/ch01.html#_why_was_wombatdialer_created

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface), would be easier to program with a deamon running in the back to control what gets dialed and the responses to those dials. Mora info here https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239.