# calling a number from asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

I am  generating a outbound call in asterisk using .call file
my call file

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/08*******
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: outgoing
Extension: 4******
Priority: 1
Callerid: 4******
```

when the call file is called it routes to outgoing context of extensions.conf
My server calls the above number then my dialplan forward it to other to set up complete call.**Can i set up call between server and a number?** means using my server directly to call to a number and use my system as a phone to talk to that particular number
Is it possible?
thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not programming related.

Comment: Also it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154944/generating-an-outgoing-call-in-asterisk by same user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to use a softphone by which you can call directly from softphone but you have to have a sip account and have to add sip settings in sip.conf

Check [how to set up softphone](http://www.technologylair.org/2014/01/creating-asterisk-pbx-how-to-configure.html)